# Changing search slug from + to - (hyphen)

Tags: search, slug

I've been fiddling with this all day, where I'm trying to change my search function from website.com/s?this%20is%20an%20example to website.com/tag/this-is-an-example to no avail.

I have this code in my snippets:

```
/** * Change search page slug. */

function wp_change_search_url() {
    if ( is_search() && ! empty( $_GET['s'] ) ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url( "/tag/" ) . urlencode( get_query_var( 's' ) ) );
        exit();
    }  
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wp_change_search_url' );
```

This is theoretically supposed to do what I want it to and I'm so close to solving this. But my urls now come out as /tag/this+is+an+example/ instead of /tag/this-is-an-example/

Any ideas? Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP's [`urlencode()`](https://php.net/urlencode/) function replaces spaces with `+`s, so that's why that's happening for you.

WordPress provides the [`sanitize_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_title/) function, which is used (among other things) to generate a post slug from the post's title.

```
/** * Change search page slug. */

function wp_change_search_url() {
    if ( is_search() && ! empty( $_GET['s'] ) ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url( "/tag/" ) . sanitize_title( get_query_var( 's' ) ) );
        exit();
    }  
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wp_change_search_url' );
```

Comment: Wow this is exactly what I needed, thank you!